# Loading Textures using DirectXTex

Tags: graphics, textures, directx-11, texture2d

I recently just got Visual Studio Ultimate 2012. I've heard that the D3DX Utility Library is deprecated in Windows 8 Metro-style Apps so I've decided I'll try not to use the functions in them.

Now, as far as I know, I think I have two options.

1. Load textures manually, getting values for each pixel and pass them into the pInitialData argument in the CreateTexture2D function.
2. Use the DirectXTex library (which I have no idea how or even where it is...)

Can anyone help me? It would be especially nice if you could post some example code on both methods as I believe they all will come in handy. If it is not asking too much, could you explain in detail about how to use the DirectXTex library, like where to download it, how to include it in your project and how to use it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For your usage case, you probably want to use the DirectX Tool Kit rather than DirectXTex. In any case, the options for loading textures without D3DX are covered in this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/04/direct3d-11-textures-and-block-compression.aspx).

More generally, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx) are a bunch of options for replacing D3DX utility library functionality.